# $s(n)=n+2$ and Peano axioms

Tags: real-analysis, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

Define $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ given by $s(n)=n+2$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ and $s$ satisfy

- every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ has only one sucessor and $s$ is one-to-one.
- exists at least one element of $\mathbb{N}$, which is not sucessor of any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
  But they don't satisfy the Finite induction principle

Here it is my progress: given $m, n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s(m)=s(n)$. So, $m+2=n+2$. From the cancelation, $m=n$.

From the definition of $s$, we have $s(\mathbb{N}) =\{3,4,\dots\}$, which means that 1 and 2 do not have successors.

Finally let's consider $X=\{1,3,5,\dots\}\neq\mathbb{N}$. Then, $s(1)=3\in X$ and if  $p\in X$, so
$$ s(p)= p+ 2 \in X $$.

Do you agree with me?

Comment: as you have it, it appears $X = \{2n+1 : n \ge 0 \} $ or in words, the odd non-negative integers. If we have $p \in X$ then we found $s(p+1) = p +3 $ and $p+3$  is even thus $p+1 \notin X$ is what you mean in your last line ' $p+3 \in X $ ' (Is what you have currently )

Comment: @coffemath As the addition is defined in $\mathbb{N}$, a set "bigger" than $X$, may I consider it closed for $X$?

Comment: Marcos--- I was using closure of any set $A$ under $s$ to mean only "if $x \in A$ then $s(x) \in A.$ Maybe your phrasing "closed *for* X" could mean the same as what I just said about closed under X,

Comment: I have made a few changes